# What is the best way to say "Thank you for helping make the conference a success" in Spanish?

Tags: traducción

Not sure if I would need to use subjunctive. This is what I have but I'm not sure if it's right "Gracias por ayudar a que la conferencia sea un éxito"

Thank you!

Answer (score 2):

The sentence:

1. Gracias por ayudar a que la conferencia **sea** un éxito.

is correct if the conference is in progress or to be held in future.

However, "helping" and therefore "make" in the sentence in English:

- Thank you for helping make the conference a success.

can be interpreted as referring to the past:

2. Gracias por ayudar/ haber ayudado a que la conferencia fuera un éxito.
3. Gracias por ayudar / haber ayudado a que la conferencia haya sido un éxito.

The difference between (2) and (3) is that in (3) the conference has just finished, while in (2) the conference finished some time ago.